# Best way to determine the equality of two data sets in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, simplify

Do you know a simpler way to achieve the same result as this?
I have this code:

```
color1 = input("Color 1: ")
color2 = input("Color 2: ")

if ((color1=="blue" and color2=="yellow") or (color1=="yellow" and color2=="blue")):
            print("{0} + {1} = Green".format(color1, color2))
```

I also tried with this:

```
if (color1 + color2 =="blueyellow" or color1 + color2 =="yellowblue")
```

Comment: While [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) might be a good place to suggest going for this type of question, we should get out of the habit of sending question-askers over there. Please read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) meta post for clarification.

Comment: Stop referring code review please. Read the links I posted in my comment on why we need to stop doing this.

Comment: set([color1, color2]) == set(["yellow", "blue"])

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `set`s for comparison.

> Two sets are equal if and only if every element of each set is contained in the other

```
In [35]: color1 = "blue"

In [36]: color2 = "yellow"

In [37]: {color1, color2} == {"blue", "yellow"}
Out[37]: True

In [38]: {color2, color1} == {"blue", "yellow"}
Out[38]: True
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't miss the *bigger picture*. Here is a better way to approach the problem in general.

What if you would define the "mixes" dictionary where you would have mixes of colors as keys and the resulting colors as values.

One idea for implementation is to use immutable by nature [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s as mapping keys:

```
mixes = {
    frozenset(['blue', 'yellow']): 'green'
}

color1 = input("Color 1: ")
color2 = input("Color 2: ")

mix = frozenset([color1, color2])
if mix in mixes:
    print("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(color1, color2, mixes[mix]))
```

This way you may easily *scale* the solution up, add different mixes without having multiple if/else nested conditions.